# Apple's DVD Player won't run (and why is hidden)

Tags: dvd, dvd-player

I am selecting some old DVD's and CD's - to keep or garbage? Some old DVD's won't open in Quick Time neither VLC. So I decided to try the Apple's DVD Player since it seems burned to old dedicated DVD players. Is not in Applications list, is hidden, why?

Anyway, I tried to run it but it just shows up the interface and collapse. Here is the first part of the crash report...

```
Process:               DVD Player [6754]
Path:                  /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/DVD Player.app/Contents/MacOS/DVD Player
Identifier:            com.apple.DVDPlayer
Version:               6.0 (5500.72)
Build Info:            DVDPlayerX-72000000000000~580
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           DVD Player [6754]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-03-26 16:33:42.965 -0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.3 (19D76)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        5D622C4B-9B9A-1324-5B1E-10A7B6CBB1AA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       BC5508BC-7AFC-4870-A114-9C25B077134A

Time Awake Since Boot: 36000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       21000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

It is possible to make it work? Why it's hidden? Any third part suggestion for Catalina?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like those discs might be corrupted and therefore might not be able to be read by any application.

However, if you wanted to try one more thing before throwing it away, I would recommend either [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) or [MakeMKV](http://makemkv.com) to "rip" the contents to your hard drive.

If they don't work, I would consider the data lost unless it contains something extremely precious or valuable.

Comment: I found an app inside, maybe the file is in a proprietary format. But the app is 32 bits, so I will need a Mojave... An what about the Apple's DVD Player?

Comment: Apple's DVD player only plays movies or such, so anything out of the ordinary will confuse it.